# Cocoa - Audio - How to differentiate microphone from speaker

Tags: objective-c, macos, avfoundation

I am studying the AVFoundation framework and for this purpose, based on Apple sample codes, I create a small app that shows the power level of a selected input device.

I use a NSPopupButton with binding values to list items to be select as AVCaptureDevice

The binding content refer to an NSArray `audioDevices` generated by the following code:

```
- (void)refreshDevices {

    [[self session] beginConfiguration];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"audioDevices"];
    if (_audioDevices) [_audioDevices release];
    AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession *captureDeviceDiscoverySession = [AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession discoverySessionWithDeviceTypes:@[AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInMicrophone]mediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio position:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
    _audioDevices = [[captureDeviceDiscoverySession devices]copy];

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"audioDevices"];
    if (![[self audioDevices] containsObject:[self selectedAudioDevice]])
        [self setSelectedAudioDevice:nil];

    [[self session] commitConfiguration];
}
```

This  works well except that it provides all audio devices (both Microphone and Speaker available on Bluetooth).

How can I select the Microphones only?